# Ruby submit 2 forms with one submit button

Tags: html, ruby

Is there a way, without using javascript, to have two forms in one view and submit both by clicking on one submit button?

I have the following in my views:

```
<%= form_for(@attendee) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@event_attendee) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :attendee_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :attendee_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :event_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :event_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The following is my controller:

```
  def registration
    @event=Event.find(params[:id])
    @attendee=Attendee.new
    @event_attendee = EventAttendee.new
  end
```

Comment: No, not without javascript.

Comment: Ok got it! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You don't need two forms since i am.pretty sure there îs a relationship between attendee and event_attendee...this suggests an attendee belongs to an event and an event has_one attendee ( this is just an asumption) so i am pretty sure You can use a single.form with 'fields_for' and merge the two forms into a single.one.. check here https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `form_for` helper with a plain html:

```
<%= form_tag(registration_path, method: "post") do %>
  <input type="text" id="attendee[name]">
  <input type="text" id="event_attendee[attendee_id]">
  <input type="text" id="event_attendee[event_id]">
  <%= submit_tag('Submit form') %>
<% end %>
```

From this form your controller will receive those params:

```
{
  attendee: { name: 'Alex' },
  event_attendee: { attendee_id: 20, event_id: 30 }
}
```

And with these params you can do whatever you need further.